# Save String and String[] from method into poll [ ][ ]

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, methods

I'm having trouble trying to save an assigned String and String[] from a constructor method into an 2-dimensional array and then print it out. The idea behind the program is adding a person to the doodle program with their name and their answers (in voegDeelnameToe) and then print out all the information through geefPollInfo().

I'm trying to add several persons trough the voegDeelnameToe() method but I can't save the String deelnemer (= String 'name of participant') and String[] aanwezigheden (= String[] 'answers') to the String [][] poll; Therefore I also can't print out the information about the poll. Any ideas on how to save the information from several persons from a doodle.voegDeelnameToe into the String [][] poll?

```
doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Bram",new String[]{"ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja"});
        doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Katja", new String[]{"nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
        doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Kristien", new String[]{"ja", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
        doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Peter", new String[]{"ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
        doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Sven", new String[]{"nee", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "ja", "ja"});
        doodle.voegDeelnameToe("Matthias", new String[]{"ja", "ja", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja", "nee", "nee", "nee", "ja", "nee", "ja", "ja", "nee", "ja"});
        System.out.println(doodle.geefPollInfo());

public class Poll {

    boolean type;
    String titel;
    String omschrijving;
    String locatie;
    String initiator;
    final int MAX_DEELNEMERS = 10;
    LocalDate[] data;
    LocalTime[] tijdstippen;
    String[][] poll;          // The array to save the information
    String einde = " ";
    boolean afgesloten;
    int teller = 0;

    public Poll(String testBasispoll_1, String dit_is_de_eerste_basispoll, String gent, String bram_Gosseye, LocalDate[] data, LocalTime[] tijdstippen, boolean b) {
         titel = testBasispoll_1;
         omschrijving = dit_is_de_eerste_basispoll;
         locatie = gent;
         initiator = bram_Gosseye;
         this.data = data;
         this.tijdstippen = tijdstippen;
         type = b;
    } 


    public String geefPollInfo() {

        System.out.println("Titel : " + titel);
        System.out.println("Omschrijving : " + omschrijving);
        System.out.println("Locatie : " + locatie);
        System.out.println("Initiator : " + initiator);
        System.out.println("Max aantal deelnemers : " + MAX_DEELNEMERS);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Dag \t \t" + data[0] + "\t \t" + data[1] + "\t \t" + data[2] + "\t \t" + data[3] + "\t \t" + data[4]);
        System.out.println("Uur \t \t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2] + "\t" + tijdstippen[0] + "\t" + tijdstippen[1] + "\t" + tijdstippen[2]);

        return einde;
    }

    public boolean voegDeelnameToe(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden) {

      return type;
    }

   /* public boolean wijzigDeelname(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden){

      return type;
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays have a fixed size when instantiated. Entries in the array need to be managed explicitly with indices. You can't append a new value to an array, it is necessary to specify the index to store the value at.

A `String[][]` is an array of arrays of strings. It is an array that expects an array of `String` in each index. Each entry is initialised to `null`.

Using a `List<String[]>` may be a better choice for storing the arrays passed in using the `voegDeelnameToe` method. The `List` interface has an `add` method that appends to the end of the list. It also grows dynamically as it needs to.

If you really want to use an array you will need to manage the next index to assign to and allocating a new, larger, array when you need more space.

You also want to store the `deelnemer` with the `aanwezigheden`. There are several ways to do this. You can maintain two separate lists, one of `deelnemer` and one of `aanwezigheden` and use the same index to keep the values together. You can create a new array, 1 larger than `aanwezigheden`, set the first entry to `deelnemer` and copy `aanwezigheden` into the remaining entries and store that. The cleanest way is to create a private inner class that holds the two parameters and have a list of those.

```
public class Poll {

    private final List<PollEntry> poll;

    public Poll(...) {
        ...
        poll = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    ...

    private static final class PollEntry {
        private final String deelnemer;
        private final String[] aanwezigheden;

        private PollEntry(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden) {
            this.deelnemer = deelnemer;
            this.aanwezigheden = aanwezigheden;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also remember that entries in an array can be changed. So you should consider copying the `aanwezigheden` to prevent the array the `Poll` class has being changed after it has been passed to the `voegDeelnameToe` method. Only something you need to do if thread safety or mutability are concerns.

```
Arrays.copyOf(aanwezigheden, aanwezigheden.length)
```

You can traverse a `List` in `geefPollInfo` using a foreach loop.

```
for (PollEntry entry : poll) {
    System.out.println("Deelnemer : " + entry.deelnemer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a data structure that implements the `Map<K, V>` interface.  For example:

```
public class Poll {
  ...
  HashMap<String, String[]> poll;
  ...

  public boolean voegDeelnameToe(String deelnemer, String[] aanwezigheden) {
    poll.put(deelnemer, aanwezigheden) //saves the String and String[] as a pair
    ...
    return type;
  }    
}
```

`HashMap` stores data in key, value pairs.  Instead of being indexed numerically like an array, the unique key will be the value of `deelnemer`.  `poll.get(deelnemer)` would return the String[] `aanweizgheden`.  Here is a link to the `HashMap` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).